# Searching in multiple classes using playframework's search-module

Tags: lucene, search-engine, playframework

As described at [playframework - search module](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.0/search), I've installed the search-module. Of course my model consists of multiple classes. I'd now like to search for entries whose attributes consist of several tables, i.e. i'd like to search for users who have bought an article that costs more than say 500$ whereas there would be a table for customers, one for orders and one for articles.

Does anyone know how to realize this using the playframework's lucene-query-language?

thanks a lot!

Comment: by the way, i'm using search-module version 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query language isn't specific to Play!  You can learn about the syntax from the official Lucene documentation: http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_0_0/queryparsersyntax.html